# OSX Command line: echo command before running it?

Tags: macos, shell

I am writing an OSX command line which will run EXIFTool thousands of times against individual images. Sometimes the commands fail and its very difficult to see where its failing because it doesn't list which line.

Here is how my .command file looks:

```
exiftool - ABC
exiftool - DEF
exiftool = GHI
```

Here is how the output looks when successful:

```
/Users/User/Desktop/script.command ; exit;
    1 image files updated
    1 image files updated
    1 image files updated
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...258 completed.
```

How can I get it to tell me which command ran before the output?

Thank you!

Comment: Run the script with the `-x` option.

Comment: That is to say: `bash -x yourscript`, or put the command `set -x` inside the script itself.

Comment: Thank you both! This worked!!!!!!!